# How to fix a log in issue after resizing your hard drive?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, hard-drive, login

I am running Ubuntu on the Oracle VirtualBox. I was running out of room on my virtual hard drive (8GB) so I resized it to 16GB. Now when I try and log in I enter my password and the the screen flashes with lines then it goes back to the login with no error message or anything but I am able to log in as a guest.

Comment: Can you log in on the virtual terminal (accessible with Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: Yes I can log in with Ctrl+Alt+F*

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+Alt+F2 to open a console and then remove the Xauthority file. If that doesn't fix it, try reinstalling xorg.

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
sudo reboot
```